# How to check if isset HTTP Get method in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

How to check if isset HTTP Get method in JavaScript or JQuery?

We are in page with bellow url:

```
https://example.com/blog?page=2
```

and i want to check if isset `Get method` or not:

```
<script>
  if (isset(method.get)){
    // yes is set
  }
</script>
```

What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  const Get = new Proxy (new URLSearchParams (window.location.search), {
    get: (searchParams, prop) => searchParams.get (prop),
  });

  if (Get.page){ // page is the ?page=3
    // yes is set
  }
```